# How to effectively monitor http in Jenkins

Tags: performance, http, jenkins, monitoring

Is there some way effectively monitor http in Jenkins master? Monitor plugin provides some graphs and tables but it is really hard to understand how the end user ‘feels’ while working on the Jenkins web page. Is there any page freezes? What is the maximum delay? Maybe I don’t use the Monitor plugin correctly, so is there any way to harvest such a data from provided graphs?

Answer (score 0):

The monitoring plugin is the one that I use.  It tells me which pages are taking the longest time to load/hang/etc. I"m not sure if there is something else out there that can do something like this.  Maybe a third party tool like newrelic perhaps.

[image]